# How to see the source code of R .Internal or .Primitive function in dnorm?

Tags: r

The R source code of dnorm is:

function (x, mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE) 
.Call(C_dnorm, x, mean, sd, log)

How can i see the source code of dnorm in C_dnorm?

Comment: I came to the same question and can not find the answer neither with the link provided in the closing message, nor with those in the answer here. I can see `dnorm4` function, but not that of the `C_dnorm` function.

Answer (score 1):

you find in https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/dnorm.c
or 
https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/dnorm.c
this code is in C program